# How can I see the OP's new comments if the OP deleted his question after commenting?

Tags: support, comments, deleted-questions

Quick question:

So a user asked a question which did not get any answers, so I was helping him in the comments. Then he commented further questions but deleted the question right after. I think he does not know that now I can't respond. Anyway I see the notification and part of the comment in my inbox in the upper panel however I can't see it all.

It says `Page Not Found` if I press on the notification. Is there anyway I can still view his added comments if the question is deleted now?

Comment: You can also ask in chat for a 10k user to take a look and quote the comment or post a screenshot.

Comment: Cool @sh ! I will try that. Thanks :)

Comment: Cheers! For the record, "@sh" didn't ping me, you must use at least three letters. (I got pinged because I'm the only one commenting, besides you. :))

Comment: Oh.. well I thought it works with at least one char if no duplicate user exists ! :D Maybe it was working because of "no user else". Thanks for the lesson :) Would you do that for me btw? Tell me what his name and/or what he asked for maybe I can ask him to come to a chat or something

Comment: It's all explained [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work). As for the comments, I need a link to the question, and I'll post a screenshot. :)

Comment: Cool :D! Then there IS a way :D Thanks. See here: [**The Deleted Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531159/sort-bounding-boxes-to-reconstruct-curves?noredirect=1#comment64456769_38531159)

Comment: No problem, here is the whole comments discussion: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fsF1h.png and the [user chat profile](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1410918/cchacholiades). :)

Comment: What goes around comes back around :D "_Many thanks for your comments_" ;)

Comment: lol, my pleasure! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you won't be able to view the question or the OP's comments unless you have 10K reputation.

However, if you feel the person self-deleted their question after getting help and did so in an abusive way, you can flag for moderator attention to ask the moderators to undelete the question.  They might or might not grant such a request:

- If the question got an answer and then the OP self-deleted (e.g., before the answer could get any upvotes), that's considered abusive and moderators will typically undelete in that case.
- If the question didn't get an answer and only got comments, that's a bit different and moderators might not choose to forcibly undelete.

  [ Yes, this is good motivation to either answer in an answer (if the question is clear enough to provide a full answer) or vote/flag to put it on hold as 'unclear' until the question is clarified enough to be answerable (if the question isn't clear enough to provide a full answer). ]

Since the post is deleted, you won't be able to flag it yourself.  Instead, if you want to flag it, find some other post (e.g., one of your own posts) and flag it for moderator attention with a custom message, and link to the deleted question.